# Creating models for storing grouped images in specified order

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a little problem with designing database.
On webpage i need to display image by 4 with specified order but not every image  in quad has to be uploaded.

**Option1:**

I created a model image_quad with fields img1,img2,img3,img4

Every image will link to other project so i had to add new fields anw it look like

```
img1, img1_project_id, img2, img2_project_id, img3, img3_project_id, img4, img4_project_id
```

the problem is how to bind that model to Projects? It doesnt use cake convention (project_id) and i think writing `$this->Project->find()` for every `img(x)_project_id` isnt good.

**Option2**

Model Quad

Model QuadImage with `[id][quad_id][project_id][image][order]`
Where order is place in quad (1,2,3,4)

It is better but now, how to display images in good places in view ? I mean QuadImage with 'order' 3 on 3rd place etc. 
I can't write them one by one because in some quads there could not be all images.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's a pretty bad approach to handle file references. What you're after is basically a set of images, you call it quad, I would call it gallery or collection. A proper DB design for that would be something like that for example.

> Project hasOne Gallery, Gallery hasMany Image

Each file should be a single record for multiple reasons. Each project has a set (gallery) of images.

I don't fully understand what you try to do but this might work as well:

> Project hasAndBelongsTomany Image

The join table will have the order field to give them a specific order. This DB design will work for you in the case you want to sure multiple images.

Checkout my [FileStorage plugin](https://github.com/burzum/FileStorage), it will take care of the file handling and keeps references to them.